# Windows store app Get data from sql

Tags: sql, rest, windows-store-apps

I'm new to making Windows Store apps and I have to make one for school. (They didn't bother to explain it to us). So with 3 other projects going I'm going to ask you guys.

What is the best way to read and display data from an MSSQL?
Let's say that I wanna click a button and it shows me everything from a table, E.G: (SELECT * FROM LineUps)
I searched for REST services already but i don't find a lot of information, and what's with the async calls?

Thanks

Comment: so you want offline solution or server?

Comment: Thanks for your response, offline will be fine. It just needs to get his information from the sql server with windows authentication